# In which format should ISRC IDs be included in an Ogg comment field?

Tags: metadata, oggvorbis

ISRC codes, which identify the recording that a track contains, can be encoded two ways, human-readable and machine-readable:

```
AA6Q72000047
AA-6Q7-20-00047
```

and for completeness there's also `ISRC AA-6Q7-20-00047`

Which format should I use in the "comment" field "ISRC=" in an OGG file? The only example I could find on the net was on
https://www.legroom.net/2009/05/09/ogg-vorbis-and-flac-comment-field-recommendations

```
ISRC=132938420384
```

which isn't a valid ISRC!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solutions at ISRC com have replied to my query:

> Always without dashes.
>
> The dashes are only for ease of reading when the code needs to be read out to someone over the phone or something...